# Products show only in admin when adding via Magento 1.9 Custom Wishlist SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v1

**Requirement**: I am a newbie in `magento` trying to make a custom `SOAP` API in Magento 1.9 for managing wishlist. I need to connect it to an android application being developed in ionic V1.
At first i tried to use this extension [magento-api](https://github.com/leoliew/magento-api) but could not find a way to maintain session information in android. So, i moved to developing my own API.
I am able to fetch wishlist information(wishlist_id, items etc) and add to it.
 
**Issue**: But after adding a product in the wishlist via soap call, it is only shown in the admin area for the customer and not on the front-end of the website(User is logged in). Only products added from front-end(browser) are shown on front-end wishlist page.
After comparing the functionality from the front-end(`/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php`) with my Api.php(shown below) seems like my `$buyRequest` variable is missing some 'form-key' but i do not understand magento too much to understand this.

I have added the Api.php at `/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/ModelApi.php`.

My code to add product to wishlist is as follows:

```
public function create($customer_id, $product_id, $store = null){
    $return_result = array(
        'code' => 0,
        'msg' => null,
        'model' => null,
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'product_id' => $product_id
    );
    $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array());
    $params = array('product' => $product_id,
            'qty' => 1,
            'store_id' => $store,
            );
    $buyRequest->setData($params);

    $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer_id, true);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);

    Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();
    if($result){
        $return_result['msg'] = 'Product '.$product_id.' Added ';
        $return_result['model'] = $result;
    }  
    return json_encode($return_result);
}
```

I used the following link to implement the add functionality and used some code in the from the `/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php` file: [add catalog product in wishlist programmatically in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423186/add-catalog-product-in-wishlist-programmatically-in-magento?rq=1)


Any help would be appreciated.